# How to change the size of TextPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, size, jtextpane

hi i'm working with java gui atm. Playing around with textPane and textArea. I know how to change the size of a textArea, but how do i change the size of a textPane? I've been trying to look up ways to do it, but it seems like most the topics are on changing font size nothing really on the pane size itself.....so is there a way to change the size of a textPane? if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the component is controlled by the layout manager.

1. Set a proper `LayoutManager` for the `Container` containing the `JTextPane`.
2. Optional: Set proper constraints for the `JTextPane`
3. Let AWT/Swing lay out and resize the component accordingly.

**Further reading:**

- [The Java™ Tutorials: A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)